# @Autowired doesn't work in method parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, kotlin

Here is my AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
class AppConfig{
    @Bean("myname")
    fun name(): Name = Name("Quang")
}
```

Data class:

```
data class Name(val value: String ="")
```

My Controller Class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class Main{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    fun index(@Autowired @Qualifier("myname") name: Name): Name {
        //this return ""
        return name
    }
}
```

The result is "" instead of "Quang".
But now if I inject it from field like this, it works fine:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class Main{
    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("myname")
    lateinit var name:Name
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    fun index(): Name {
        //this return "Quang" as expected
        return name
    }
}
```

So can you explain why @Autowired doesn't works when I use it in method parameter

Comment: That's a handler method. It's invoked when you receive a request and Spring MVC determines that it's meant to be handled by that method. Spring MVC doesn't do any type of `@Autowired` injection. There are a number of supported parameter types (some with annotations) and those are documented in the spec.

Comment: After reread the docs, i realize this is really a stupid question :(. @Autowired is meant to be used in field, constructor and setter method.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be
>   autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.

In your first example, Spring will not autowire anything.